# UPBGE - Is it possible to cast desktop onto texture?

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to make a launcher: Is there a way to cast the desktop onto a plane?

Something like this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xy4JKvqsV4
And this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950962/screen-sharing-in-python

The question is if it's possible to implement it on bge?

Comment: Not sure exactly about a Desktop stream, but you can certainly get a webcam's stream and place it onto a material's texture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81QDf1A8yAI

Comment: How about setting the background transparent to the desktop? It's not streaming or casting, however via using a transparent background it might show the desktop. Could it be possible?

Comment: OS Desktop's don't support transparency to my knowledge. If you're referring to the Desktop stream, yes. Simply enable transparency for your mesh's material and adjust the alpha value for it.